# Vector of vector with unknown size input in c++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to input elements of vector of vector. Size of vectors is not known.

Row input ends with * character, as well as vector input.

EXAMPLE

```
2 5 1 3 4 *
9 8 9 *
3 3 2 3 *
4 5 2 1 1 3 2 *
*
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::vector < std::vector < int >> a;
  int x;
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for (;;) {
    while (std::cin >> x) {
      a[i][j] = x;
      j++;
    }
    if (!std::cin >> x) break;
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This allows me to enter only the first row, and after that the program stops. Could you help me to modify this to allow input of other rows?

Comment: `a[i][j] = x;` ... `a` is of size 0. `a[i]` is undefined. You need to use `push_back` and `resize` appropriately. Before the `while` you can do `a.resize(i+1)`, and inside the while loop do `a[i].push_back(x)`

Comment: You also need to clear the error state when `std::cin >> x` fails. Your current method won't really work for finding the end of the file...

Comment: When it encounters the `*`, `cin >> x` puts the stream in an error state, and returns without reading to `x`  AND leaves the `*` in the stream.   The next call of `cin >>x` returns immediately, without reading to `x`, due to the error state.    To fix that (and continue using `cin >>`) you need to BOTH clear the error state and remove the pending `*`.   Weakness of that is that it can, in some circumstances, discard good input - so values read are wrong.   Better option is to not use `cin >> x` - instead read all input from `cin` as a string (e.g. using `std::getline()`, and parse the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. you are indexing into each `vector` without adding any values to it first, which is *undefined behavior*. `a[i][j] = x;` does not make the vectors grow in size.  Use `vector::push_back()` instead.
2. You are not handling the input of `*` correctly.  `x` is an `int`, so when `std::cin >> x` fails to read a non-integer value, like `*`, `cin` is put into an error state and all further reading fails until you `clear()` the error and `ignore()` the failed data from the input buffer.

Since your input is line-based, consider using `std::getline()` to read each line at a time.  You can use a `std::istringstream` to read integers from each line, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> std::ws;
    if (iss.peek() == '*') break;
    std::vector<int> v;
    int x;
    while (iss >> x) {
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    a.push_back(v);
  }
  for(auto &v : a) {
    for(int num : v) {
      std::cout << num << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you add code to print result of input on screen?

Comment: @Amar OK, added.